# Stop loop when value is true

Tags: vba, excel

I want do loop in excel until the value is true, but how could I finish my loop?

```
Sub doUntil ()
'Do until the cells value is True.
    Dim columnNo As Integer
    Calculate
    'Refreshing the database.
    columnNo = 45
    'The True or False Cells are in the AS column
    Do
    Cells(columnNo, 45).Interior.Color = RGB( 253, 0, 0)
    Loop Until True
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't increasing your `columnNo` variable in any way...

Comment: You should be using conditional formatting for this any ways which isn't a programming question.

Comment: It's in one column.

Comment: You need to edit your post to explain what you actually want your Loop to accomplish.

Comment: (a) `until the value is true` - what "value" needs to be true?  (b) `Cells(columnNo, 45)` is a bit confusing because you are using a variable called "columnNo" to refer to the row number.

Comment: I want to make a macro.

Comment: Since you definied ColumnNo to be 45, your `Cells(column,45)` is really `Cells(45,45)`  Nothing is changing.  If all your information is in one column, you need to augment your row by one in each loop.

Comment: My bad, I am a newbie... I would like to make a loop process with recalculating until it finds the value.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are iterating through the rows in your columnNo column, then you'll need to declare that variable and increment the value on each loop. Then test if your `AS` column is `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
Sub doUntil ()
'Do until the cells value is True.
    Dim columnNo As Integer, rowno as integer
    Calculate
    'Refreshing the database.

    'this is the column "AS" that has True/False values
    columnNo = 45

    'This is your starting row
    rowno=2

    'The True or False Cells are in the AS column
    'Starting at row number rowNo loop until we find "True" in column 45/AS
    Do Until Cells(rowno, columnNo).value = "True"

        'Paint the cell
        Cells(rowno, columnno).Interior.Color = RGB( 253, 0, 0)

        'increment your rowNo to the next row
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
    Loop 
End Sub
```

The big change here is that we are iterating through all of your rows starting at 2 until we hit a row where column `AS` has value "True" in it. If you don't increment your row then your loop will never exit, and that's bad.

Alternatively you could do this in a For loop:

```
 Sub doUntil()
       Dim columnNo as Integer, rowNo as Integer
       Calculate

       columnNo = 45

       For rowNo = 2 to 200 'start and end for the loop
            If Cells(rowNo, columnNo).value <> "True" Then
                Cells(rowno, columnNo).Interior.Color = RGB(253,0,0)
            Else
                Exit For
            End IF
       Next RowNo
 End Sub
```

Or using a range object in the for loop...

```
 Sub doUntil()
       Dim rngColumn as Range, rngCell
       Calculate

       set rngColumn = Columns(45)

       For each rngCell in rngColumn.Cells
            If rngCell.value <> "True" Then
                rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(253,0,0)
            Else
                Exit For
            End IF
       Next RowNo
 End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer to a bad question.

Comment: Actually the best response! Thank you JNevill and @Chrismas007 please forgive me for my stupid question for your Grace...

Comment: The only thing that was bad about it was that it shows a lack of research before asking since Loops are heavily documented with many examples around the internet, but... I know what it feels like to deal with programming concepts for the first time. It's overwhelming for sure.

Comment: I'd point out 1) your codes are _language dependent_, since a cell containing a `True` boolean result would match "True" string only for English language, thus for a non English Excel it could iterate over, and paint, ALL column cells. To avoid it use ` Do Until Cells(rowno, columnNo)` or `If Not Cells(rowNo, columnNo) Then` and the likes. And then your last code should care to avoid header cell (if any) 2) your 2nd could be simplified to `For rowNo = 2 To 200 - If Cells(rowNo, columnNo) Then Exit For - Cells(rowNo, columnNo).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 0, 0) - Next rowNo` and similarly 3rd code

Answer (score 0):

if your aim is to color red all cells containing "FALSE" from cell "AS2" down to the last consecutive "FALSE", then you can avoid loops and act as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub doUntil()
    Dim f As range

    Calculate 'Refreshing the database.
    With Worksheets("MyLoopSheet") '<--| change "MyLoopSheet" with your actual sheet name
        If .range("AS2") Then Exit Sub '<--| if the first value is "TRUE" then you have nothing to do!
        With .range("AS2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AS").End(xlUp)) '<--| consider column "AS" cells from row 2 down to its last non empty one
            Set f = .Find(What:=True, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| let's look for the 1st "TRUE" in the column and consequently grab the last consecutive "False" as the preceeding cell
            If f Is Nothing Then Set f = .Rows(.Rows.Count + 1) '<--| if there's no "TRUE" value in the column then set 1st virtual "TRUE" cell one after the last
            .Resize(f.Row - 2).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 0, 0) '<--| color all "FALSE" cells in one go
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

both avoiding loops and acting on cells in one go can significantly reduce computing time

Comment: @DominikMajsai: did you get through it?

Comment: @DominikMajsai: it'd be nice of you to give feedbakcs to people trying and help you